# jQuery "Snap To" Effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a specific effect I want for a website I'm building. As you can see in [this website](http://risenchurch.com/), I want the screen to "snap to" the next section after the user scrolls, but only **after** (not the instant) the scroll event has fired. The reason I don't want to use a plugin like [panelSnap](http://guidobouman.github.io/jquery-panelsnap/) is because I 
 1: Want smaller code and 
 2. Want the website, when viewed on mobile, to have more of the "instant snap" effect (try reducing the browser size in the website mentioned above). I know I theoretically could try combining *two* plugins, like panelsnap and scrollify, and activate them appropriately when the browser is a certain width, but I don't know if I want to do that... :( 
So all of that said, here's the code:

```
var scrollTimeout = null;
var currentElem = 0;
var options = {
    scrollSpeed: 1100,
    selector: 'div.panels',
    scrollDelay: 500,
};
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $snapElems = $(options.selector);
    console.log($($snapElems[currentElem]).offset().top);
    function snap() {
        if ($('html, body').scrollTop() >= $($snapElems[currentElem]).offset().top) {
            if (currentElem < $snapElems.length-1) {
                currentElem++;
            }
        }else{
            if (currentElem > 0) {
                currentElem = currentElem - 1;
            }
        }
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $($snapElems[currentElem]).offset().top
        }, options.scrollSpeed);
    }
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(window).innerWidth() > 766) {
            if (scrollTimeout) {clearTimeout(scrollTimeout);}
            scrollTimeout = setTimeout(function(){snap()}, options.scrollDelay);
        }else{
            //I'll deal with this later
        }
    });
});
```

My problem is that every time the `snap` function is called, it triggers the scroll event, which throws it into a loop where the window won't stop scrolling between the first and second elements. Here's the poor, dysfunctional site: https://tcfchurch.herokuapp.com/index.html Thank for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a boolean to record when the scroll animation in `snap` is in progress and prevent your `$(window).scroll()` event handler from taking any action.

Here's a working example:

```
var scrollTimeout = null;
var currentElem = 0;
var options = {
    scrollSpeed: 1100,
    selector: 'div.panels',
    scrollDelay: 500,
};
$(document).ready(function() {
    var scrollInProgress = false;
    var $snapElems = $(options.selector);
    console.log($($snapElems[currentElem]).offset().top);
    function snap() {
        if ($('html, body').scrollTop() >= $($snapElems[currentElem]).offset().top) {
            if (currentElem < $snapElems.length-1) {
                currentElem++;
            }
        }else{
            if (currentElem > 0) {
                currentElem = currentElem - 1;
            }
        }

        scrollInProgress = true;
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $($snapElems[currentElem]).offset().top
        }, options.scrollSpeed, 'swing', function() {
            // this function is invoked when the scroll animate is complete
            scrollInProgress = false;

        });
    }
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if (scrollInProgress == false) {
            if ($(window).innerWidth() > 766) {
                if (scrollTimeout) {clearTimeout(scrollTimeout);}
                scrollTimeout = setTimeout(function(){snap()}, options.scrollDelay);
            }else{
                //I'll deal with this later
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The variable `scrollInProgress` is set to `false` by default. It is then set to `true` when the scroll `animate` starts. When the `animate` finishes, `scrollInProgress` is set back to false. A simple if statement at the top of your `$(window).scroll()` event handler prevents the handler from taking any action while the `animate` scroll is in progress.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using the well known fullPage.js library for that? Check out this [normal scroll](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/normalScroll.html) example. The snap timeout is configurable through the option `fitToSectionDelay`.
And nothing to worry about the size... it is 7Kb Gzipped!

> I know I theoretically could try combining two plugins, like panelsnap and scrollify, and activate them appropriately when the browser is a certain width, but I don't know if I want to do that

fullPage.js also provides `responsiveWidth` and `responsiveHeight` options to turn it off under certain dimensions.